# Migrate Silex v1.3 to v2, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I recently migrate Silex v1.3 to v2 by changing 3 lines in the composer.json

```
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "silex/web-profiler": "~2.0",
    "deralex/yaml-config-service-provider": "2.0.x-dev"
```

But since a lot of class can't be found by Silex...

Here is my app.php file, correctly load everything I need in Silex 1.3:

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider;
use Manager\ManagerProvider;

$app = new Application();
$app->register(new UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new ValidatorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider());
$app->register(new HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
$app->register(new SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new FormServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'translator.messages' => array(),
));
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), [
    'security.firewalls'    => [
        'foo'     => [ 'pattern' => '^/foo' ],
        'default' => [
            'pattern'   => '^.*$',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'form'      => [ 'login_path' => '/login','check_path' => 'connexion' ],
            'logout'    => [ 'logout_path' => '/logout' ],
            'users'     => $app->share( function () use ( $app ) {
                return new Authenticate\UserProvider( $app['manager.user'] );
            } ),
        ],
    ],
    'security.access_rules' => [
        [ '^/.+$','IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' ],
        [ '^/foo$','' ]
    ]
]);
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
    // add custom globals, filters, tags, ...

    return $twig;
}));

$app->register(new DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider(__DIR__ . '/../app/settings.yml'));
$app->register(new ManagerProvider($app));

return $app;
```

First error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in app.php line 15:
Attempted to load class "UrlGeneratorServiceProvider" from namespace "Silex\Provider".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Second error:

```
UndefinedMethodException in app.php line 33:
Attempted to call an undefined method named "share" of class "Silex\Application".
```

Third error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in app.php line 56:
Attempted to load class "YamlConfigServiceProvider" from namespace "DerAlex\Silex".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "DerAlex\Pimple\YamlConfigServiceProvider"?
```

Fourth error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in ManagerProvider.php line 12:
Attempted to load interface "ServiceProviderInterface" from namespace "Silex".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface"?
```

I don't know what should be change and how correcting that...
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `UrlGeneratorServiceProvider` was replaced by `RoutingServiceProvider`

   `$app->register(new RoutingServiceProvider());`
2. Method `share` was removed from `Pimple`. Just set function that returns object to share some object.

   `$app['object'] = function() { return new Object(); }`
3. May be composer is not set to autoload classes with namespace `DerAlex\...`. Try to use `\DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider`.
4. Add use statement `use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface` or use this class as `\Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thans @Max, it's ok for point 1 & 2, but for the 3: YamlConfigServiceProvider, I try to add a "use DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider", "use DerAlex\Pimple\YamlConfigServiceProvider;", there is no change. the file YamlConfigServiceProvider.php is located in vendor\deralex\yaml-config-service-provider\src\DerAlex\Pimple

Comment: than remove `use DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider;`, add use `use DerAlex\Pimple\YamlConfigServiceProvider;`and use it as `$app->register(new YamlConfigServiceProvider(...`

Comment: Ok for the point 3, thanks ! :) For the 4: ServiceProviderInterface, I add a "use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;" but the probleme still here. The ServiceProviderInterface.php file is locate to vendor\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple

Comment: I think I have to change "use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;" by "use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;", but the class seems to has changed... :( "Compile Error: Declaration of Manager\ManagerProvider::register(Silex\Application $app) must be compatible with Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface::register(Pimple\Container $pimple)"

Comment: Add `use` statement where class is used, in your case in `ManagerProvider.php`

Comment: I did add "use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;" in my ManagerProvider.php class. I get the error above

Comment: yeah, change declaration in `Manager\ManagerProvider` to `register(\Pimple\Container $app)` :)

Comment: It's better ! xD But I get another error :'( : "LogicException in TranslationServiceProvider.php line 35: You must define 'locale' parameter or register the LocaleServiceProvider to use the TranslationServiceProvider"

Comment: follow the instruction from error message, register `LocaleServiceProvider` same as other service providers

Comment: Indeed. I add a use Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider; and add the 'locale' => 'fr', parameter to the $app->register(new TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'translator.messages' => array(),
    'locale' => 'fr',
)); It seems to work. So thanks @Max ! I get another error now. I will make another stack post.